# Why using struct with variadic template parameter makes two template instantiation at the same time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm wondering why this program is not working as expected .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <list>

template <typename... Args>
struct prank
        : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 9> {};

template <template <typename...> class C,typename T, typename ...Args>
struct prank<C<T,Args...>>
        : std::integral_constant<
        std::size_t,
        1+ prank<Args...>::value> {};

int main()
{
    using T = std::list<int>;
    std::cout << prank<T>::value << "\n";
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/bTfvfs)

The output is 11 but it should be 10 .

**Let me explain why :**

In `main()` we call `prank<T>` with `std::list<int>`.

It has 2 choice,by resolution rule,it choose the second specialization of template .

Then in :

```
  template <template <typename...> class C,typename T, typename ...Args>
    struct prank<C<T,Args...>>
```

`C` becomes `std::list` , `T` becomes `int` , `Args` is `empty`

Then we inherit it from

```
std::integral_constant<
            std::size_t,
            1+ prank<Args...>::value>
```

second variable of `std::integral_constant` become `1 + prank<Args...>` , `prank<Args...>` itself  will call the first prank's struct with empty Arguments pack and after inheriting from `std::integral_constant` value member of that struct become 9 .

So `1+ prank<Args...>::value` should become 1+9=10 not 11 !!

But it seems that `prank<Args...>` makes and use 2 struct at the same time ! (`struct prank<C<T,Args...>>` and `struct prank` )

Is it a bug or I'm making a mistake ? (I'm using gcc 4.8.1)

Comment: Actually, `Args` is `{std::allocator<int>}`, not empty. See the problem?

Comment: I told you you'd drown in a forest of bizarredom if you follow down this road :-) I chose the name `prank` rather much on purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Introduction

The problem is that you are assuming that `std::list` only have *one* template-argument, causing the instantiation of `prank<std::list<int>>`, which will cause instantiation of `prank<int>`.

This is however incorrect, and it's because `std::list` has a default-template parameter following your `int`, namely the allocator: `std::allocator<int>`.

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class std::list;
```

```cpp
std::list<int> => std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>
```

---

#### Explanation

```
template <typename... Args>
/* (A) -> */ struct prank : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 9> {};

template <template <typename...> class C,typename T, typename ...Args>
/* (B) -> */ struct prank<C<T,Args...>>
        : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1+ prank<Args...>::value> {};
```

**instantiations, in order**:

1. (B) `prank<std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>>`
2. (B) `prank<std::allocator<int>>`
3. (A) `prank<int>`

The total value yield? **11**.

Comment: I think the second `prank` is actually `prank<std::allocator<int>,int>`, but that doesn't affect anything

Comment: @MooingDuck it's not, the `int` (being `T`) is not used to instantiate the nested `prank`

Comment: Huh, [you're right](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66c59a76ae143a49), but it really seems like it ought to be deducing that.

Comment: @MooingDuck not really, the `int` you are referring to is swallowed by the `T` in `prank<C<T, Args...>>`. ie. having `prank<std::list<int,std::allocator<int>>>` `C = std::list`, `T = int`, and `Args... = { std::allocator<int> }`.